# Uninstall XTerm

Tags: command-line, uninstall, xterm

I unintentionally downloaded XTerm and UXTerm. GNOME Terminal is working just fine for me for now (I'm new to LINUX), and I don't want to have XTerm and UXTerm on my computer if I'm not using them.  It doesn't appear in the "Installed" category in Ubuntu Software. I don't know if there's a command to remove it, but I can't find one.

Comment: How did you "install" them? There's probably an "unistall" or "remove" possibility.

Comment: What do you mean by "unintentionally downloaded"? How do perform the act of "downloading" without "intent"? Do you mean "mistakenly downloaded", or just plain "downloaded"?

Comment: I probably downloaded it along with something else.  I didn't do it intentionally, I just noticed them in my applications one day and didn't know what they were.

Comment: Mistakenly is probably the better word, yes.

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt list --installed | grep Term`?

Comment: @cocomac I just found a solution thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: @waltinator Thank you for your help as well

Answer (score 2):

I found an answer at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250081

Since it seems just the package and no other library would be removed, I would proceed to remove it:

```bsh
sudo apt-get purge xterm
```

That seems to have removed it.